# Small Black Fly Identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Could anyone help to identify the following small black fly please?

[image]

[image]

Here is some relevant information which may help:

- Location: London, UK
- Length: ~5mm
- They are slow to react and drift lazily & silently around a room

After my own research, I thought it might be a fungus gnat, but I'm uncertain.

Hopefully, if the species can be reliably identified, I can then look to find out what attracts them and how to deter them.

Comment: We need a photo with the wing venation in focus for a reasonable chance at family-level identification; if on getting such a photo the family is Sciaridae (which does seem likely given the animal's color), good luck (species level identification in that group is firmly in the "some disassembly required" camp).